# Black boxes instead of text in UI in Android app

Tags: android

I have an Android app in the Play Store. In the last couple of days I've started getting bug reports about "black blocks in the settings screen". Unfortunantely I haven't been able to reproduce the bug on my devices, so everything I know comes from user reports.
I've got the following screenshots from a helpful user:

http://madscientist.pl/temp/bug0.png

http://madscientist.pl/temp/bug1.png

There's supposed to be white text on the tab headers, on the buttons and next to the radio buttons and seek bars. There should also be white horizontal lines separating the options.

The sizes of those black boxes that are visible (the rest is on the black background) correspond to the sizes of letters that are supposed to be there. The text on the two columns of buttons reads "Save" and "Load".

My app can be opened in two modes: live wallpaper and as a "regular app". The problem apparently exists in both versions.

Almost all bug reports describe another characteristic: **the settings screen sometimes works correctly and sometimes it doesn't. E.g., sometimes opening the settings activity of the live wallpaper for the second time fixes the problem.**

Another person wrote that it works correctly on the first application run only. After that, he has to clear the app data and then again it fails on the second run. So it seems that the bug manifests itself rather unpredictably.

I admit to not being a very good dev and that all the text is put directly in the layout files instead of in strings.xml. It was never an issue before, but just in case I'm in the process of establishing if putting the strings in strings.xml helps with one of the users.

The problem seems to be independent of the device. I've got reports from Samsung, Motorola, LG and Nexus users.

From what I've established so far, for at least one of the users the problem happens on both current and previous version of my app. The previous version was in the store since January 2015. The current version is a month old. I've been getting bug reports for just over a week now so this doesn't seem to be (directly) caused by some change I made to the app.

This led me to believe that the new Android version that has been rolling out recently (at least I've got 5.1 a week ago) is the reason. However I've got bug reports from a user who runs the app on 5.0.2 and 4.4.4.

The app is moderately popular and has a stable amount of downloads, so the fact that in the last week I've got a dozen reports of this bug, and before that I've never heard of it, leds me to believe that it indeed started happening over a week ago. **So apart from the bug itself, it's really beyond my understanding what made it appear just now, if neither application update nor system update seem to be related.**

I could provide more data, but the question is already terribly long. Let me know what else you think could be helpful.

Comment: I guess it depends on a `bad theme customization`. Ask your users if they are using a `custom ROM`. I say so, because I have a similar problem using a `custom ROM` on a device (white text on white background).

Comment: Make the question simple & clear . It is very hard to read this one.

Comment: @DonChakkappan Well, I'd love to make it simpler, but as I said, I don't have this bug on my devices, I can't produce a minimum example and I only rely on users' bug reports. I had to provide some context too. If you have anything specific in mind, please let me know, so I can rewrite or rephrase it.

Comment: By the way, on all my devices using a CyanogenMod ROM, this doesn't happen. On a device with a custom MIUI ROM I have this issue.